# Find all and replace function in Sibelius

Tags: software, sibelius

How can I do this operation? I have an issue here: I exported MusicXML file from Guitar Pro 6, opened it in Sibelius and I saw a `tab` word on the end of every bar

[image: I highlighted the word that I need to remove from everywhere in this score]

It will take too long to remove them manually so is there a function that can remove this object (in this case) from everywhere in the score?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use the Advanced Filter?

In Sibelius 8, it's under the Home Tab. Shortcut key is Alt+Ctrl+Shift+F.

It's not super intuitive, but try using it to select all the clefs. Something like this:

[image]

Note that you can select multiple clefs by holding down Ctrl and clicking. I note that there are duplicate percussion clefs, so you may want to select them as well.

This also assumes you have everything selected- the filter filters the selection, unless you change "Find in" to "Whole score".

Once you've run the filter, all the clefs should be selected. Then just press delete to remove them all.

I'm assuming the objects are actually clefs, and not a symbol or something weird. Regardless, with some experimentation, you should be able to use the filter to just select those objects, and then delete them.

Comment: Kinda helps, but not really. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @EugenEray In what way could it be improved? I'm sure someone around here should be able to help.